# Error visualiza imagen, Lienzo en Canvas con Scrollbar, Pero Genera este error: itemconfigure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tagOrId'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, canvas

Alguien me puede ayudar, estoy colocando una imagen en un lienzo con barras de desplazamiento vertical y horizontal, ya aparece las imagenes, pero genera el error que pongo al final, no veo donde estoy equivocado, no manejo muy bien canvas.

```
def visualizar_imagen_consulta(self):
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2 = Toplevel()
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.transient(self.windows_consulta1)
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.geometry("655x600+700+0") #"670x500+10+50"

    query = 'SELECT * FROM visuales WHERE ID_IMAGEN_VISUAL = ?'
    parameters = (self.miid_nombre_imagen.get(), )
    db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)
    for database_visuales2 in db_rows:
        self.midescripcion_imagen.set(database_visuales2[4])

    self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1="/oftica/visuales/" + self.miid_nombre_imagen.get()

    img_frame = tk.Frame(self.windows_fichas_consulta2, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6')
    img_frame.pack()
    canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

    sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    img = Image.open(self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1) 
    width, height = img.size
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
    image_on_canvas=canvas.itemconfig(image = image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')
```

Muestra la imagen, sin problema, pero genera el siguiente error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 2566, in ver_imagen1
    self.visualizar_imagen_consulta()
  File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 2665, in visualizar_imagen_consulta
    image_on_canvas=canvas.itemconfig(image = image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')
TypeError: itemconfigure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tagOrId'
```

Agradezco cualquier orientación que me puedan o referirme a un publicación. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Modifique mi código y ahora me present la imagen sin problema, pero ahora, generar el error descripto y no logro ver porque lo hace, si me pueden orientar, mucho lo agradeceria, Saludos y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola comunida, sigo trabado con este error, si alguien me puede orientar

Comment: comunidad, corrigo, disculpen

Comment: No puedo publicarlo como respuesta porque no se ve... Pero tu consola dice que el método `itemconfigure()` le falta un argumento llamado `tagOrId` por lo que revisa las lineas donde llamas ese método y asegurate de mandar la cantidad de parametros correctos

Comment: Gracias por comentar, ciertamente falta un argumento pero la verdad no se cual es

Comment: Revisa donde tiene referencias tu método, asegurate que todos los lugares mandes la cantidad de parametros necesarios

Comment: Creo que simplemente sobra el `image=` que has puesto en el parámetro. Yo pondría simplemente en la última línea `canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')` (y sin asignar el resultado que devuelve)

Comment: File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 3262, in visualizar_imagen_consulta
    canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2903, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fill"

Comment: Hola – abulafia, gracias por la sugerencia, si uso esta linea, "canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')", genera el error que he colocado en los comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido la respuesta al problema

Primero puse global img2

```
    global img2
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Segundo

```
image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
```

Entendi que al usar image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2), devuelve un int que se usa para identificar el elemento de lienzo específico (su id). Por ellos simplemente cambie la linea a:
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)

Mi codigo que de la siguiente manera:

```
    img_frame = tk.Frame(self.windows_fichas_consulta2, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6')
    img_frame.pack()
    canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

    sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    global img2
    canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    img = Image.open(self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1) 
    width, height = img.size
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
```

Visualiza la imagen, se desplaza por las barras horizontales y verticales de desplazamiento y ya no genera error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta  :D

Comment: Gracias, por recordar

Answer (score 1):

El error “falta 1 argumento posicional requerido: 'self'” se genera cuando no crea una instancia de un objeto de una clase antes de llamar a un método de clase. Este error también se genera cuando crea una instancia incorrecta de una clase.

Para resolver este error, asegúrese de crear una instancia de un objeto de una clase antes de intentar acceder a cualquiera de los métodos de esa clase. Luego, asegúrese de usar la sintaxis correcta para crear una instancia de un objeto.

Y luego añades el argumento faltante:

```
itemconfigure(self.score, image = image_on_canvas, fill = 'black')
```

Nota: el self puede ser .score, .ply... depende lo que quieras, la documentación de canvas te haría bien darle una repsada).

Éxitos

Comment: Hola @Amilcar Angeles, agradezco la explicación, no tengo experiencia en Python y no entendi la respuesta. Trate de seguir tus instrucciones pero creo que por mi falta de conocimeinto me sigue generando errores

Comment: Si alguien me puede ayudar, coloque una recompensa que ya caduco, la recompensa fue cobrada o pagada segun la respuesta que enviaron, sin embargo, esta no resolvio mi problema y tampoco me respondio mi comentario, como que solo queria la recompesa que me imagiono le fue asignadada, aun sigo trabado.

Comment: Hola @Juan carlos Pantoja, no estaba disponible y no siempre lo estamos. Una cosa es la respuesta a la pregunta original y otra muy distinta es la respuesta a una pregunta de un comentario, a otra pregunta generada después de una respuesta o por el desconocimiento del tema. Es la importancia de saber preguntar.